# Can i create file in NSMainBundle in ios app? what is the meaning of this code?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, unzip, zip

I have a zip file in NSMainBuddle (code.zip) inside code.zip two file names.txt,group.txt, now i want to add one more file to code.zip file, ie  i am trying to add Demo.txt.

```
- (IBAction)CreatezipAction:(id)sender{
ZipFile *zipFile= [[ZipFile alloc]initWithFileName:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"code" ofType:@"zip"] mode:ZipFileModeCreate];
 ZipWriteStream *stream= [zipFile writeFileInZipWithName:@"Demo.txt" compressionLevel:ZipCompressionLevelBest];   
    NSString* str= @"Sample String…………";
    NSData* data=[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
    [stream writeData:data];
    [stream finishedWriting];
}
```

its successfully adding to NSMainBunble because if i click button corresponding to  lisAllFileAction: its will show like this….

```
- (IBAction)lisAllFileAction:(id)sender {
    ZipFile *unzipFile= [[ZipFile alloc]initWithFileName:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"code" ofType:@"zip"] mode:ZipFileModeUnzip];
    NSArray *infos= [unzipFile listFileInZipInfos];
    for (FileInZipInfo *info in infos) {
        NSLog(@"- %@ %@ %d (%d)", info.name, info.date, info.size, info.level);        
    }
}
```

output on simulator
2

```
012-06-04 11:55:42.143 zipDemo[1757:207] - code-Zip/names.txt 2012-5-30 17:19:00 +0000 983 (-1)
2012-06-04 11:55:42.143 zipDemo[1757:207] - code-Zip/names.txt 2012-06-01 20:07:50 +0000 2563 (-1)
2012-06-04 11:55:42.144 zipDemo[1757:207] - Demo.txt 2012-06-04 06:25:40 +0000 12 (9)
```

1. Now i want to know can manually open this Demo.txt?
2. what is the difference b/w code-Zip/names.txt 2012-06-01 20:07:50 and Demo.txt 2012-06-04 06:25:40 +0000 12 (9)?
3. Can create file in in NSMainBundle like this, any problem for app?
4. Actually where Demo.txt file created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mainBundle` is **read-only**. You can't write nothing in the mainBundle, you can just load. You should create your files in the `Documents` or `Caches` directory. So, the first time the app starts, you can copy the zip file from the mainBundle to the Documents directory, and then use this instead the zip file in the mainBundle.